# How do I change the ICER graphical output in R's ICEinfer to natural units

Tags: r

In R's excellent ICEinfer package which graphically plots incremental cost-effectiveness ratios from a bootstrap replication to denote uncertainty, the output by default is expressed in terms of cost (or effectiveness) units on both x and y axes.

The code is

```
dpunc <-ICEuncrt (
  your.data, 
  treatment group, effectiveness, cost, 
  lamda=? (shadow price of health), 
  R= (number of bootstrap replications)
)
```

I want to plot the scatter plot in its natural units, i.e. costs on the y axis (which will always be large numbers) and effectiveness on the x axes (which will be small numbers - like QALYs i.e. 0.10, 0.20 etc.). For publication (say in journal papers) I think it is wise that a scatter plot has each variable (change in cost (y) and change in effect(x) in its natural units.  I don't know how to change the graph or set it up so that it plots in natural units along the x and y axes.  Any suggestions?